# how to initialize static char array with NULL(or 0) in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, null, char, initialization

I attempted to initialize char array with NULL like this syntax.

```
char str[5] = NULL;
```

But it returned error..
How can I initialize char array with NULL or 0 in C++?

Concretely, I want to print "Hello" in this example code.

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
 char str[5] = NULL;
 if(!str)
  std::cout << "Hello" << std::endl;
 return 0;
}
```

This code will return error because of incorrect initialization. Then, what initializing sentence should I replace sentence with?

Comment: Arrays aren't pointers. What exactly do you want to achieve?

Comment: You could have `char *str = NULL;` Are you planning to modify `str` later or it remains `NULL`?

Comment: With `if(!str)` you are checking if the pointer to `str` is `NULL` not if the content is `0x0`

Comment: the array will not be 0, as it will decay to pointer and it will have a memory address. <you could initialize the array with {}>
or you could use a pointer, that may have a bit more sense

Comment: `if(!str)` - will never be true. `str` is an automatic variable with a determinate, non-null address. It does not have, and never will have, an expression value of `NULL`. You need something that can hold `NULL`, and that is a *pointer*. `char *str = NULL;`, for example.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

An array can not be null. Null is state of a pointer, and an array is not a pointer.

In the expression `!str`, the array will decay to the address of the first element. The type of this decayed address is a pointer, but you cannot modify the decayed pointer. Since the array is never stored in the address 0 (except maybe in some special case on an embedded system where an array might actually be stored at that memory location), `!str` will never be true.

What you can do, is initialize all of the sub-objects of the array to zero. This can be achieved using the value-initialization syntax:

```
char str[5]{};
```

As I explained earlier, `!str` is still not meaningful, and is always false. One sensible thing that you might do is check whether the array contains an empty string. An empty string contains nothing except the terminator character (the array can have elements after the terminator, but those are not part of the string).

Simplest way to check whether a string is empty is to check whether the first character is the terminator (value-initialized character will be a terminator, so a value initialized character array does indeed contain the empty string):

```
if (!str[0]) // true if the string is empty
```

Comment: When I initialized integer pointer with NULL, it worked well.
This is an example. 
<code>
#include <iostream>
int main() 
{ 
 int *a;
 a = NULL;
 if(!a) std::cout << "Hello" << std::endl; 
 return 0; 
}
</code>
 Only char array's name can't be initialized with NULL?

Comment: @favdew it has nothing to do with `char`, and everything to do with the difference between an array, and a pointer. A pointer stores a memory address. The address zero is the null pointer. An array is a sequence of objects in memory. It does not store an address.

Comment: @user2079030 As I know, array's name has memory address pointing its first value's address in C  Language. Is it different in C++?

Comment: @favdew It is not so in C++, nor in C.

Comment: @favdew That has never been true. Although, it is a common misconception.

Answer (score 3):

```
//...
char str[5] = {'\0'};
if (str[0] != '\0')
//...
```

If you now put some characters into str it will print str up to the last '\0'.
Every string literal ends with '\0', you must make sure your array ends with '\0' too, if not, data will be read beyond your array (until '\0' is encountered) and possibly beyond your application's memory space in which case your app will crash.

You should use std::string or QString however if you need a string.

Comment: You don't need C++ 11 for this syntax. It would even work in C.

Comment: Every const char* ends in '\0' would be better stated something like every C style string end in '\0'. There's nothing about const char* that says it has to be used for C style strings.

Comment: True, you don't need C++ 11 for that initialization. You only need it when using a vector or other collection, not a plain array.

Comment: I would amend the comment by @john to say that every *string literal* (rather than "C-style string" or `const char *`) ends in `'\0'`.

Comment: @JaMiT John's comment is more complete. A string literal is just a special case of C-string.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit What guarantees the existence of a null terminator for something other than a string literal? Yes, there is a more complete answer than "string literal", but I would be hesitant to suggest that everyone always terminates their C-strings properly.

Comment: @JaMiT Nothing guarantees that a null terminator is present but, if it isn't, you don't have a C-string. An array of characters terminated by a null terminator is a C-string; that's the definition of C-string. If you forgot the null terminator then you just have an array of chars.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit There is something off in the logic here. If someone knows that definition of a C-string, then it's pointless to tell them _"every C-string ends in '\0'"_ since that's part of the definition. If someone does not know the definition of a C-string, then using the term "C-string" is useless as the intended meaning will be missed; maybe they'll think the compiler adds the '\0'. ...If this answer is supposed to be about non-literal strings in C, then it probably should start with a full description of the concept, as the asker apparently does not understand it.

Comment: @JaMiT I'm not debating what you should or should not tell people, I'm merely correcting your claim that a C-string can lack a null terminator.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit where did I claim that a C-string can lack a null terminator?

Comment: @JaMiT Your first comment, which said that every string literal, _rather than C-style strings_, ends in '\0'. The implication of that statement is that you think not every C-style string ends in '\0', otherwise you'd find john's comment just fine. If that's not what you meant, feel free to clarify your comment.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit You are misreading that comment. I guess I could clarify it using quotes instead of indirect speech: __I would amend the comment by john to read _"Every const char* ends in '\0' would be better stated something like every string literal ends in '\0'."_ (i.e. change "C style string" to "string literal", still in contrast to "const char*").__ The parenthetical part highlights the change being made; it is not part of the change. It just happens to fit better in the middle of the statement when quotes are not being used.

Comment: @JaMiT Can you explain why you think that amended version of john's comment would be better than the original? Because, again, john's original comment is accurate and complete, whereas your amended version is not, so I can't understand why you're suggesting the change unless you've misunderstood something about null termination! In other words, I'm not getting where specifically string literals come into this at all, because the fact being described is true of _all_ C-strings.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Because "complete" and "understandable" are often at odds with each other, particularly when a question is asked at a low level of understanding. (In other words, this is about what you should tell people.) I would say john's comment is fine if the question indicated some basic understanding of what constitutes a string in C. However, it does not. A string literal, though, is used properly, so that suggests a possible starting point for an explanation. (I am not going to address "accurate" because despite your insinuation to the contrary, my amended version is accurate.)

Comment: @JaMiT I never insinuated, nor do I claim, that your amended version is inaccurate. I said that it's not both accurate and _complete_, which is true! It just seems strange to deliberately reduce the scope of the statement to something that is potentially more misleading than the original comment. Ah well.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit when there is no word following "not" in the clause _"[X] is accurate and complete, whereas [Y] is not,"_ the implication is that Y is neither accurate nor complete. Taken literally, that clause does merely say that Y is either not accurate or not complete, but the implication is that Y is both not accurate and not complete. To avoid that implication, the word "complete" should follow "not" (or the words "accurate and" could be dropped).

Comment: @JaMiT If you've inferred a meaning that, by your own admission, is not the correct meaning, then that's on you :) I think we should stop this discussion now. Have a good day!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Looks like we're discussing related, but separate, topics again. (I'm discussing how to avoid miscommunications in the future, while you're discussing who the blame is on in the past.) So, yeah, we're done here.

Comment: @JaMiT We were done 16 days ago - why do you feel the need to bring it up again? Just stop.

Answer (score 1):

You can't initialise a char array with `NULL`, arrays can never be `NULL`. You seem to be mixing up pointers and arrays. A pointer could be initialised with `NULL`.

You can initialise the chars of your array with 0, that would be

```
char str[5] = {0};
```

but I don't think that's what you're asking.

Answer (score -3):

```
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {

char str[5];
for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
    str[i]=NULL;
}
printf("success");
return 0;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: `str[i]=NULL` is wrong. `NULL` is a macro for a pointer literal. You shouldn't use it to initialize a character. Some hull pointer literals are character literals too (like `0`), but others are not (`nullptr`), so this is not guaranteed to work.

Comment: I tried to run the above code and then gave 'h e l l o' as input to str and it works fine on my machine.I also run the same on codechef ide and it works fine there as well. https://www.codechef.com/ide

Comment: I never did say, that it would be guaranteed to not work. I said that it's not guaranteed to work. There is a difference. Surely you would like your program to compile on all standard compliant compilers, not just the one on your machine and on codecef?

Comment: All you've done is set each `char` to `0`. Surely not your intention, nor does it answer the question. Without a more precise definition of what you mean by "it works fine", this is not the answer.